# IPP v2 error when creating Invoices

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

Over the past 48 hours, we started seeing this error popping up for our customers, across hundreds of dozens of realms/accounts. This is happening with code that has been in production for > 6 months without any changes.

In searching on Stack Overflow and Google, I haven't been able to find anyone else with thie issue. The error response we get is included below. Has anyone else ran into this problem, and if so, do you know of a solution?

I've searched for -3002, -6502 and 20009 error codes for Intuit, QuickBooks, etc, with no luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
  <Error RequestId="a9cc80085bc14cb79fb23b47396ae3dc">
    <RequestName>ErrorRequest</RequestName>
    <ProcessedTime>2015-09-16T15:18:06.845Z</ProcessedTime>    
    <ErrorCode>-3002</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDesc>p_main fetch full object response -6502</ErrorDesc>
    <DBErrorCode>20009</DBErrorCode>
  </Error>
</RestResponse>
```

Comment: Did you try making a support ticket with Intuit? Hundreds of dozens of accounts sounds pretty major!

Comment: Yep - I did. Just hoping for a solution in less than 48 hours, but doesn't sound like that's going to happen.

Comment: Error went away.. but now it's back again.